# hyper-v ip address periodically changes - how to make it stop?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, ip-address

My Hyper-V machines IP address was 172.18.60.119 and now it's 192.168.158.71. How might I give it some fixed IP address like 127.0.0.50 or something else?

FWIW I'm using Vagrant to create these VMs.

Comment: That’s two entirely different subnets

Comment: How are you distributing IPs to your VMs?

Comment: @LeRouteur - I'm using Vagrant to create the VMs so however Vagrant is doing it but once they're launched the IPs still none-the-less change and it's a little annoying lol